# Change color of an id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new at this. I would like to know if you can help me. I wold like to chance the color of an id (a rectangle). I want the color to change every 5 seconds to some colors i already have chosen and when clicked on the rectangle, it will assume the color at the time.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you look at some basic tutorial ? `$('#someid').css('color', 'red')` is very basic.

Comment: @dystroy: Actually `background-color` is probably what he wants

Comment: @dystroy also he want's it to change every 5 seconds!

Comment: @Liam well. There's `setInterval` too, but OP is supposed to fix one problem at a time, not give us his whole specification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you should select your element using jQuery id selector (http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). For example if you element is named "MyElement" then you should write $("#MyElement")

After selecting an element you can call some jQuery functions to it. In your case you can call .css() function to change the background color propery of your rectangle (may be div element?). So the code will be like $("#MyElement").css("background-color", "red");

You can predefine colors in JavaScript array: var colors = ["red", "green", "blue"]; and then create a method that will be called every 5 seconds (using JavaScript method setInterval) and will change the color.

I have wrote the whole code for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Ww74t/

HTML:

```
<div id="MyElement"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#MyElement {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];
var currentColorIndex = 0;
$("#MyElement").css("background-color", colors[currentColorIndex % colors.length]);
setInterval(function(){
    currentColorIndex++;
    $("#MyElement").css("background-color", colors[currentColorIndex % colors.length]);
},5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="rectangleId">Test</div>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(function(){
    var myArray=['red','yellow','blue'];
    $('#rectangleId').on('click',function(){
        var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
        $(this).css('color', rand);
    });
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/3QMuT/

For **Automatic change** in every 5 seconds use the above code like:

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(function(){
    var myArray=['red','yellow','blue'];
    setInterval(function(){
        var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
        $('#rectangleId').css('color', rand);
    },5000);
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/3QMuT/1/

**Note:** You have to add any `jQuery version` before using it.